# How to get Media Item from Asset Url

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Have asset url stored as NSstring, how to get MediaItem corresponding to the url from itunes media library.

Using following code

```
@objc func getMyMediaItem(SongUrl:NSString)->Void{

    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery();        
    let urlQuery = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value:SongUrl,forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL,comparisonType: .EqualTo);
    query.addFilterPredicate(urlQuery);
    let mediaItem = query.items! as [MPMediaItem]; 

  }
```

But mediaItem is always returning 0 items.

Comment: Query by persistent id helps.

http://stuffnobodytoldmeabout.blogspot.in/2011/05/checking-if-mpmediaitem-exists-by-url.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From assetUrl, persistence Id is computed and query by Id.

```
@objc func getMyMediaItem(SongUrl:NSString)->Void{

    let number = SongUrl.substringFromIndex(32);
    print("my song number "+number);
    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery();
   // let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: SongUrl as String)
    let urlQuery = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value:number,forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID,comparisonType: .Contains);
    query.addFilterPredicate(urlQuery);
    let mediaItem = query.items! as [MPMediaItem]; 

  }
```

Comment: works but looks really weird to have to substring by hardcoded index.. Asked for another way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220128